# align three div blocks inside another

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align two of my blocks to the left and the last one to the right, but it aligns down. How can I take it right up?

the idea is to have 2 divs in the first row (they can be div1 and div3) and div 2 in the second row

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd; 
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

.container div:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want all three elements on the *same* line, you'll want to turn your elements into `inline-block` elements with `display: inline-block`, and then `float` the final element to the `right`:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}

.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container div:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```

If you want one element on the first line and then two elements on the second line, you'll want to give each element a `width` of `50%`, `float` the second element to the `left`, and `float` the third element to the `right`. Optionally you can also `text-align` the third element to the `right`. You'll also need to `overflow` the container.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container div {
   display: block;
   width: 50%;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: left;
}

.container div:last-child {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```

If you want two elements on the first line and then one element on the second line, you'll want to give each element a `width` of `50%`, `float` the first element to the `left`, and `float` the second element to the `right`. Optionally you can also `text-align` the second element to the `right`. You'll also need to `overflow` the container.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container div {
   display: block;
   width: 50%;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(1) {
  float: left;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: div 2 must be below 1

Comment: the idea is to have 2 divs in the first row (they can be div1 and div3) and div 2 in the second row

Comment: perfect is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd; 
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

.container div:nth-child {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container div:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: div 2 must be below 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
 .container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd; 
  padding: 1em;

}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
   float:left;
}
.container div:last-child {
  float:right;
  display: inline-block;
}

<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex here. Giving margin-left:auto to last div, will move the item to the right as available free space will be given to left dimension. You can apply auto to margin in any direction like top, right, bottom or left.

```css
body{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd; 
  padding: 1em;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.container1 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.container div:last-child {
  margin-left: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container1">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use `display: flex`, and finding use of pseudo element little bit confusing,

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="flex: 0 0 50%; max-width: 50%;">
    <h3 style="background: lavenderblush">Div 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 0 0 50%; max-width: 50%; order: 3">
    <h3 style="background: pink">Div 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 0 0 50%; max-width: 50%;">
    <h3 style="background: lightgoldenrodyellow">Div 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```